# How to get mysql to sort out items alphabetically in natural sorting?

Tags: mysql, columnsorting

I have this table:

```
NAME      POSITION
a1         567
a2         456
a3         31
...
a134       90
...
a183       4
aa1a1      78
...
b1         8
b2         67
...
b145       3
...
bccb18     45
```

the value in POSITION should match their order when sorted alphabetically (just like on Windows) like this:

```
NAME      POSITION
a1         1
a2         2
a3         3
...
a134       134
...
a183       183
aa1a1      184
...
b1         1156
b2         1157
...
b145       1201
...
bccb18     1395
```

I tried this:

```
SET @i = 0;

UPDATE MyTable
SET POSITION = (@i := @i + 1)
ORDER BY name ASC, name ASC;
```

I get this:

```
NAME    POSITION
a1      1
a10     2
a100    3
...
```

How can I get the values sorted out in the NATURAL order? A php solution would be accepted as well.

P.S. this question has NO ANSWER yet so dont link to other questions suggesting there is the answer please.